# 18-byte block and 2-rounds structure: when to use plural?

Tags: american-english, grammatical-number, technical

I just wrote in the crypto stackexchange group something like:

> This is a cipher with 18-byte block and 2-rounds structure.

This seems inconsistent to my own eyes/ears of non-native English speaker. I vaguely justify it because *byte* is a unit (and on top of that sub-divisible), and *round* a non-divisible countable thing.

What's the appropriate rule?

Comment: I don't understand the example itself, but I *can* tell you that ***something on the tune of*** isn't remotely idiomatic. If that doesn't bother you, it hardly seems worth thinking about how best to express mathematical concepts in natural language that's not *designed* for such contexts. Note for attributive adjectival constructions involving count / quantity numbers, such as ***a four-cylinder engine,*** we nearly always use the singular, so yours should probably be ***a  2-round structure.*** You seems to be mixing the two pluralities with ***block*** and ***rounds***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: you are right, thanks for pointing it, and yes my mistake bothers me, so I fixed it! At least I learned the proper form of _to the tune of_, and when it should be used. The end of your comment looks like an answer.

Comment: What you had before was a mash-up of two different metaphoric usages. *[Something being subsidized] **to the tune of** [an amount]* and *[something identified as being] **on / along the lines of** [a description]*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: yes it was. Thanks for _along the lines of_, which indeed was what I was trying to use.

Comment: I just got Google Gemini to tell me that *When a cipher is described as having "a 2-round structure," it refers to the number of iterations of the main encryption algorithm used to scramble the data. Each iteration is often called a round.* I must say that ***18-byte block and 2-round*** looks like a really awkward "attributive adjective" to put before the relevant noun ***structure*** - but if that's how people in the business refer to such things, I won't argue.

Comment: ...maybe the problem is you're trying to shoehorn *both* "qualifiers" (blocksize and iteration count) into a *single* element modifying ***structure***. Consider rephrasing to something like *This a cipher has 18-byte blocks and a 2-round encryption algorithm*, and lose the word ***structure***.

Comment: The best rule is to copy experts. There are general rules, but there are occasional exceptions. You're better asking about terminology in the crypto SE forum than here (where people may try and Google but are less likely to be familiar with the topic), because of those exceptions.